# Grab current value of textbox and drop-down-list and output them using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, textbox, html-select

What I would like to do is output the textbox value and the drop-down-list selected value simultaneously. The reason is I would like to eventually sort results through a mysql db table. Right now... when I change the textbox it will add onto the drop-down-list value, which is what I want. But when I change the drop-down-list value, it won't recognize the textbox value and revert to when the document was loaded as the value. How do I grab both values and echo them AND be able to change them and view the changes when I 'keyup' on the textbox or 'change' the drop-down-list value. Thanks in advance.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var type_term = $("#type option:selected").text()
    var search_term = $("#search").val()
    $.post('search_db.php',{type_term:type_term, search_term:search_term}, function (data) {
        $('#search_results').html(data) 
    });
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var search_term = $("#search").val()
        $.post('search_db.php',{type_term:type_term, search_term:search_term}, function (data) {
            $('#search_results').html(data) 
        });
    });
    $('#type').change(function() {
        var type_term = $("#type option:selected").text()
        $.post('search_db.php',{type_term:type_term, search_term:search_term}, function (data) {
           $('#search_results').html(data)      
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<input id="search" type="text" value="Value">

<select id="type">
<option>Type1</option>
<option>Type2</option>
</select>

<div id="search_results"></div>
```

searchdb.php

```
$type_term = $_POST['type_term'];
$search_term = $_POST['search_term'];

echo $type_term;
echo $search_term;
```

Comment: You are explicitly declaring the values within your change functions, which makes them a local scope, and therein not accessible by other functions. remove the `var` declarations from within the `change` and `keyup` functions. This should work. [The fiddle with your code, which doesn't work as intended](http://jsfiddle.net/vfsSF/)...and then, [The fiddle removing var declarations, working as intended](http://jsfiddle.net/AJGF8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variables for both form elements on each event, rather than just the one that you are changing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var type_term = $("#type option:selected").text()
var search_term = $("#search").val()
$.post('search_db.php',{type_term:type_term, search_term:search_term}, function (data) {
    $('#search_results').html(data) 
});
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var search_term = $("#search").val()
    var type_term = $("#type option:selected").text()
    $.post('search_db.php',{type_term:type_term, search_term:search_term}, function (data) {
        $('#search_results').html(data) 
    });
});
$('#type').change(function() {
    var search_term = $("#search").val()
    var type_term = $("#type option:selected").text()
    $.post('search_db.php',{type_term:type_term, search_term:search_term}, function (data) {
       $('#search_results').html(data)      
    });
});
});
```